# Code won't run if super.windowClosing(e) doesn't exist, and it requires a ";", which causes the IDE to treat it as if it was not there

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

This is my first question on here, so any feedback about the way I asked this question would be helpful.

I am writing code that will save information to a text file when the JFrame gets closed. When I initially wrote the listener, Intellij put in that extra line of code (super.windowClosing(e)) because there was an error initially (Cannot resolve method 'add(WindowAdapter)'), so I had pressed the fix button which put in that line, but it also caused an error to pop up saying that it was missing a semicolon.

//Thread 4

```
Thread t4 = new Thread(() -> frame.add(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e)  \* ; */ {

                    try {
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Registry.txt");

                        for (String key : loginRegistry.keySet()) {
                            //write key to file
                            for (String innerKey : loginRegistry.get(key).keySet()) {
                                //write innerKey to file
                                //write get(innerKey) to file
                            }
                        }
                        writer.close();
                        frame.dispose();
                        System.exit(0);

                    }catch(IOException x){x.printStackTrace();}

                    }
                }

        }));
```

This code segment is supposed to write down a map (containing strings and maps(containing a string and a char array)) into a file, so that when the program is run again it can read the information that was saved. But the program won't run do to the error.

Comment: `WindowAdapter#windowClosing` is an empty convenience implementation of the `WindowListener` interface, so in this case, there is no need to call the `super` method

Comment: And `super.windowClosing(e)  /\* ; \*/ {` should be `super.windowClosing(e);` (and also remove the trailing `}`) but as I stated, the call isn't required

Comment: If i remove it, Intellij says, " Cannot resolve method 'add(WindowAdapter)' "

Comment: those comments were just supposed to demonstrate where the semicolon is supposed to go according to intellij

Comment: Let's also point out that Swing is NOT thread safe, so `new Thread(() -> frame.add(new WindowAdapter() {` is a bad idea

Comment: In digression, when _over-riding_ a method, make a call to the _super_ implementation of, to apply any pertinent, associated, processes.  Optional, of course, considering.  Here is the _Java_ tutorial, on _over-riding methods_, _[Overriding and Hiding Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame.add(new WindowAdapter()` is an invalid call, as `JFrame` does not have a `add(WindowListener)` method and instead, you should be using the `JFrame#addWindowListener` method, for example...

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Window is closing");
    }
});
```

Swing is also NOT thread safe.

```
Thread t4 = new Thread(() -> frame.add(new WindowAdapter() { ... })
```

is violating this rule and doesn't make a lot of sense.

This will cause the `Thread` to call the `add` method of the `JFrame`, but the call to `windowClosing` will be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread ... so it just seems completely pointless.

You should take a closer look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped. The first part helped the error, then it ran but wouldn't close. But removing the thread fixed that up.